# I want to make a functionality which can fetch real time call information using SInch API using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sinch

How I can get the real time call information on our computer using PHP and API services Sinch is providing? Do we need to make any interface kind of thing on our server and integrate Sinch APIs for that?

If we need to make an interface for it then how I can connect the phone number Sinch will provide to our interface made in PHP?

The phone numbers Sinch is providing are for real phone devices or for any computer calling software? 
If numbers are for real phone devices then is it possible for me to fetch the real time call data using PHP and APIs?
If numbers are for any computer software then do we need to make web application for it or Sinch is providing SDKs for It.?

Thanks.

Comment: If you used the below solution, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can get real time information about calls using the Sinch Reporting REST API documented here: https://www.sinch.com/docs/rest-apis/api-documentation/#reportingapi

Sinch offers the possibility to call from mobile applications (iOS and Android) and web applications. Integrating calling in your web application can be done with the Sinch JavaScript SDK available here: https://www.sinch.com/downloads/